# Adobe Photoshop, curly brackets for a publication

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I need to create a "dynamic" curly bracket for some conceptual maps that I have to write for a book.
This is the result that i need to reproduce. Can someone teach me how to do that? Thanks!

[image: Expected result]

Comment: Photoshop isn't the right software for this. It's a photo editor.

Comment: Also, what @BillyKerr says goes double for an infographic consisting of only text. Perhaps even *triple*.

Comment: @usr2564301 sure, but people do all sorts of stuff in Photoshop they shouldn't ;)

Answer (score 2):

The way I usually do this is in Inkscape or Illustrator. But other apps might work too, such as InDesign or Scribus.  You can try it in Photoshop too I suppose.

If you look at the Symbol font, there are glyphs which can be used to create one of the long curly brackets. After you've typed the characters, set the point size and leading the same. You may need to use the Glyphs dialog in your chosen application to insert the characters.

You can basically add as many of the straight line characters as needed, to make the brackets any length.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can type an open curly brace and stretch it vertically but this will distort the curves and point.

In your examples the curved ends and center points are the same size, it's the legs which are longer.

I know how to make these in Illustrator.

Type the curly brace, expand it or "create outlines".

Now with the white arrow tool you can select and only certain nodes. The legs are vertical columns and will not distort.

With the white arrow tool select all the nodes that are in the top curl only. Use the up arrow to nudge the nodes higher. Count the number of button taps so you can do the same thing to the bottom curl.

Once its the right height (compare it to the column of words), copy and paste the curly and stretch it more for the next column.

With this technique you should be able to make all the sizes of curly braces from the one starting example.

Comment: It's not what OP asked about (... a *Photoshop* solution), but as long as you're recommending Illy: would it be possible to create a brace-left only border pattern and have it expand and contract automatically when lines are added and removed?